# If $x_{n} \overset{w}{\rightarrow} x$ can we always conclude that $||x_{n}|| \to ||x||$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a Hilbert space and that $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence that converges weakly to $x \in X$.

By a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem, we can always find $f \in X^{*}$ such that $f(x)=||x||$ and $||f||=1$.

It seems to me that we must then have that $||x_{n}|| \to ||x||$ since $$||x|| = f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} ||x_{n}||$$
where the second equality follows from weak convergence of $(x_{n})$ to $x$.

I would like to use this in a proof but am new to functional analysis. Is this a well-known result, or is there a flaw in my reasoning somewhere? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can guarantee $f(x)= \|x\|$ at that one point, but not that each $f(x_n)= \|x_n\|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an infinite-dimensional hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}$, I'm sure you know that $e_n \xrightarrow{w} 0$... but, obviously, $ \|e_n\| =1 $

Check your Hahn-Banach corollary again!

Comment: Yikes! Okay, one of the reasons I ask is because I have read on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)) that $||x|| \leq \lim \inf ||x_{n}||$, and I wondered if the reverse inequality held for $\lim \sup$. But now I am confused... Any thoughts on how $||x|| \leq \lim \inf ||x_{n}||$ is justified if $x_{n} \to x$ weakly?

Comment: What do you mean? It becomes $0 \leq  1$ in this case... for $\limsup$ it does not hold. If you want to know the proof, I believe it consists on using Cauchy-Schwartz on $f(x_n)$ for some $f$

Comment: I mean in the general case not for your example

Comment: However, we can show that if $(x_n)_n$ converges weakly to $x$ then  $(||x_n||)_n$ is a bounded sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by others: this is not true. In fact: if
$$x_n \overset{w}{\to} x \quad\text{and}\quad \|x_n\| \to \|x\|$$
we even have
$$x_n \to x.$$

This follows from
$$\|x - x_n\|^2 = \|x\|^2 - 2 \, (x, x_n) + \|x_n\|^2.$$